# How to do a decision tree on MS Bot Framework?

Tags: bots, botframework

I'm building a bot for a 1st level help desk, something like:

1) Which are do you like? Products, Registration or Find a store?
2) What you want to know about products? The best product to do X? The applications of product X? Where to buy product X?

I was doing using form flow and, on completion, call or forward another flow (so I have one class for each flow, and there are thousand of them)

The problem is: when Forwarding a flow, the new flow stop responding (the prompt is executed, and any answer restart that flow - i.e. never hits .OnCompletion in the second flow =\

I was wondering: which is the best way to build complex, multi-branches bots without building a custom state machine framework on top of Bot Framework?

Comment: Which version of the bot builder are u using?

Comment: Can you post some code? Specially the forward and the second dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at [Dialog Chains](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html) ... else the custom route (depending on the depth of your tree) would be an option as well.

As to which is best , I would too like that answer ... we've gone with custom , but would like other's input.

Comment: So far, I'm going custom... but if feels that could get out of control really really fast =\