# Bot Framework: Implement finite/multi state conversation

Tags: c#, botframework

This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724632/how-to-do-a-decision-tree-on-ms-bot-framework) but I'll still go ahead and ask it.

Are there any multi-state message handlers in the MS Bot Framework that one could use and implement a conversation state machine neatly, something like the one mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454839.aspx#CreateHandlers) under the "**Handling a multi-state conversation**" heading.

I've implemented this currently by handling the user's utterance in an intent handler. The intent handler prompts the user with a question having three possible answers (for now), namely *yes / no / maybe* using:

`PromptDialog.Choice(context, AfterChoice_myUserChoiceHandlerL1, myOptionsList, ...)`

The user's answer is then handled in the `AfterChoice_myNextUserChoiceHandlerL1` method by using a switch case construct. `AfterChoice_myNextUserChoiceHandlerL1` can either end the conversation if the final state is reached, or in turn ask another *yes / no / maybe* question like this:

`PromptDialog.Choice(context, AfterChoice_myUserChoiceHandlerL2, myOptionsList, ...)`

My concern: This is indeed a quick and (very) dirty workaround and I'd therefore like to know the best way to implement this.

Comment: It's already in the Bot Framework as _activities; conversations; dialogs_.  https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html;  https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html; https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sarahsays/2016/06/27/microsoft-bot-framework-part-3-conversation/

Comment: So the way I'm implementing the waterfall using C# is kind of the way to go?

Comment: Sounds like you rolled your own?  There's nothing wrong with that but the BF has been designed from the ground up to support this sort of thing :)